# How to convert column datagridview values to strings manually?

Tags: string, vb.net, datatable, datagridview, type-conversion

How to convert column datagridview values to strings manually in VB.NET?

I tried to convert the values manually it didn't work because I wanted to use it in the print preview library but if I use another example (shown further down) it works. Is there an error in my code?

```
Public Function getData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("UserId", GetType(Int32))
    dt.Columns.Add("UserName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Education", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Location", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Double))
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Satinder Singh", "Bsc Com Sci", "Mumbai", 25000)
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Amit Sarna", "Mstr Com Sci", "Mumbai", 21000)
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Andrea Ely", "Bsc Bio-Chemistry", "Queensland", 35000)
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Leslie Mac", "MSC", "Town-ville", 22000)
    dt.Rows.Add(5, "Vaibhav Adhyapak", "MBA", "New Delhi", 27000)
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = getData()

End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

        If (e.ColumnIndex = 4) Then

            e.Value = String.Format("{0:N2}", e.Value)

        End If

    End Sub
Private Sub GenerateReport()
    KtReport1.Clear()
    KtReport1.AddString("<h2>Product List</h2>")
    KtReport1.AddHorizontalRule()
    ktReport1.AddDatagridView(DataGridView1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GenerateReport()
    KtReport1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
End Sub
```

datagridview in column price:-
[image: result datagridview in column price]
datagridview in column price in print preview report:-
[image: result datagridview in column price in print preview report]

If I use another example it works:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim random As New Random()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim productName = "Product" & (i + 1)
        Dim productPrice = random.Next(5, 5000)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {productName, productPrice.ToString("N2")})
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateReport()
    KtReport1.Clear()
    KtReport1.AddString("<h2>Product List</h2>")
    KtReport1.AddHorizontalRule()
    ktReport1.AddDatagridView(DataGridView1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GenerateReport()
    KtReport1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
End Sub
```

another example result datagridview in column price:-
[image: another example result datagridview in column price]

another example result datagridview in column price in print preview report:-
[image: another example result datagridview in column price in print preview report]

Answer results from user09938

[Result in datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMoaZ.jpg)

[Result in Print Preview (Ktreport)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Lf3.jpg)

[code kimtoo report (ktreport)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uttBW.jpg)

Comment: Please would you point out the problem to me? It appears that all the values from the DGV have appeared in the print preview. If it is a problem with converting the price values to to strings, you haven't shown the code that's doing that. (And you should use the Decimal type for money, not Double.)

Comment: You're setting the type to double in the source datatable. Your working example on the other hand is formating the value for the displaying datagridview.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , thanks your response, I've changed the data type to decimal and also before I did "DefaultCellStyle.Format" in datagridview but changed in datagridview but not in print preview. But if you see another example result DataGridView in column price in my post it changes result in DataGridView and print preview as well

Comment: @MarvinSchuchardt , thanks for your response,  before I did "DefaultCellStyle.Format" in datagridview but changed in datagridview but not in print preview.

Comment: @user18 You've forgotten to [edit] the question to add the code that does the formatting. I can only guess that you've forgotten to do the `.ToString("N2")` in the code we can't see.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , thanks reply from you , I have updated according to your request still no change in print preview . But if you see another example result DataGridView in column price in my post it changes result in DataGridView and print preview as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what `KtReport1` is, but it seems that you'd like to format the `Price` column in the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The following shows how to use a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0) with a DataGridView and how to set the [DataGridViewColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) properties.

According to [Decimal Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/decimal-data-type):

> It is particularly suitable for calculations, such as financial, that
> require a large number of digits but cannot tolerate rounding errors.

In the code below, you'll notice that if the data type of the DataTable column is `Decimal`, the `Format` is set to `N2`. Otherwise, the *Format* isn't set.

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    'create new instance
    Private _dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'initialize DataTable
        InitializeDataTable(_dt)

        'initialize DataGridView
        InitializeDataGridView(_dt)

        'bind to DataTable
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _dt

        'add test data
        AddTestData(_dt)
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitializeDataTable(dt As DataTable)
        'add columns to DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "UserId", .Caption = "User Id", .DataType = GetType(Int32)})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Username", .Caption = "Username", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Education", .Caption = "Education", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Location", .Caption = "Location", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Price", .Caption = "Price", .DataType = GetType(Decimal)})
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitializeDataGridView(dt As DataTable)
        'set property
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        'remove existing columns
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

        'add each column that exists in the DataTable to the DataGridView
        'ToDo: change/set properties as desired
        For Each dataColumn As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Dim dgvCol As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With
            {
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                .DataPropertyName = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                .DefaultCellStyle = If(dataColumn.DataType = GetType(Decimal), New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, .Format = "N2"}, New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter}),
                .FillWeight = 10,
                .HeaderCell = New DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell() With {.Style = New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter}},
                .HeaderText = If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataColumn.Caption), dataColumn.Caption, dataColumn.ColumnName),
                .MinimumWidth = 5,
                .Name = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                .Width = 100
            }

            'add column to DataGridView
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCol)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddTestData(dt As DataTable)
        'add rows to DataTable
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Satinder Singh", "Bsc Com Sci", "Mumbai", 25000)
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Amit Sarna", "Mstr Com Sci", "Mumbai", 21000)
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Andrea Ely", "Bsc Bio-Chemistry", "Queensland", 35000)
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Leslie Mac", "MSC", "Town-ville", 22000)
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "Vaibhav Adhyapak", "MBA", "New Delhi", 27000)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Additional Resources**

- [If operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator)
- [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: thanks for your answer . From the code you successfully convert in the datagridview but the result of the print preview (KtReport) results of the price column there is no format (N2) and I attach screenshots also in this post

Comment: @user18: Please add more info to your OP regarding _GenerateReport_ including code for methods/properties used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use for the generate report library which is Kimtoo.Reports. I checked there is info on github and I attach it in the screenshot with program language C#

Comment: The issue appears to be with the report library not using the format set within the DataGridView. You'll have to submit an issue to the library developer or proceed without the use of that library.

Comment: So from your code so just change it to alignment to middle right then the report library will support the format. Another one if I use "Another example result dataGridView in column price:" I create the DataGridView column manually then I don't format the alignment it works in the report library.