# VB 2019 read/write DataTable directly

Tags: vb.net, datatable

My application manages construction projects, which can change many times before product is
ordered. My goal is to create an audit trail of changes so that they can be verified or
explained to the customer, and so that mistakes and malfiance can be caught and corrected.
save a separate copy of the current record in memory.  When the record
is saved, I want to compare it to the copy in memory for changes.  If any, I want to
create a record in the same table with the original data. The DateChanged field will get the current date/time (which remains null for the original record). There is also a User_ID field to document who created this record.

My problem is figuring out how to manipulate data that is not on the user's form.  I suppose that I can create invisible text controls, but that's rather clunky.  I'm sure that there are ways to manipulate the data directly in the DataTable, but I've found no decipherable and workable example so far.  What I have found is either for VB6 (which I know but I no longer have the compiler/IDE, it won't run easily on Windows 10 and is unsupported as well)
or depends on some parameters outside the VB code they show ... please note that I
specified the parameters I used.  Idealy I'd directly read from and write to the DataTable
without involving the form at all.

The example code below is from a book, which is based on VB 2019, hence the reason I'm not using VB 2022.

Table structure:

Author      - Short Text, primary key

Year_Born   - Integer

User_ID     - Short Text

DateChanged - Date/Time

```vb
' Visual Basic 2019. The database was created in Access 2019.
' Target CPU has been set to x64.
' In Manage NuGet I have added system.data.oledb, version 6.00.
' I added the reference for "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library"
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmAuthor
    Dim BooksConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim AuthorsCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim AuthorsAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim AuthorsTable As DataTable
    Dim AuthorsManager As CurrencyManager ' Currency as in "Keeping current", not money
    Dim MyState As String = "View" ' for noticing state transitions
    Dim MyBookmark As Integer ' for cancelling adds
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        BooksConnection = New OleDbConnection ' (ConnectionString)
        BooksConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " _
            + "Data Source = C:\VBDB\BooksDb.accdb"
        BooksConnection.Open()
        AuthorsCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from Authors ORDER BY Author", BooksConnection)
        AuthorsAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        AuthorsAdapter.SelectCommand = AuthorsCommand
        AuthorsTable = New DataTable()
        AuthorsAdapter.Fill(AuthorsTable)
        txtAuthorName.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorsTable, "Author")
        txtYearBorn.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorsTable, "Year_Born")
        AuthorsManager = DirectCast(Me.BindingContext(AuthorsTable), CurrencyManager)
        Me.Show()
        Call SetState("View")
    End Sub
End Case
```

Comment: The question is lacking a question mark, so I am not sure of what answer you're looking for. Obviously we can't write your code for you. If you have tried to use the sample code and run into a specific question, ask it here. As it stands, your question is just too broad

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951980/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872634/10024425.

Answer (score 1):

That code appears to be rather old, due to the fact that it uses `BindingContext`. What you should do is add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer, then bind your `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and the `BindingSource` to your controls, e.g.

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "MyColumn")
```

If you are using a grid then the user can select a row in it. Otherwise, you can use a `BindingNavigator` to navigate or add your own navigation `Buttons` and call `MoveNext`, `MovePrevious`, etc, on the `BindingSource`.

You can get the current row from the `Current` property of the `BindingSource`.  That property is type `Object` but the item itself is type `DataRowView`, so you can cast as that type:

```vb
Dim currentRow = DirectCast(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)
```

You can then get and set fields in that row by index or column name, e.g.

```vb
Dim number = CInt(currentRow(columnIndex))
Dim text = CStr(currentRow(columnName))

currentRow(columnIndex) = number
currentRow(columnName) = text
```

A `DataRowView` can be used pretty much like a `DataRow` for most purposes but, if you need the corresponding `DataRow` specifically, you can get it from the `Row` property:

```vb
Dim currentRowView = DirectCast(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)
Dim currentRow = currentRowView.Row
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable` is an in-memory object and you can compare rows in it without binding...

```
Module Program
  Const UPDATEDATE As String = "UpdateDate"
  Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim dtb = GetDemoDataTable()
    Dim oldRow = dtb.Rows(0)
    Dim newRow = dtb.Rows(1)
    'compare rows
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each col As DataColumn In dtb.Columns
      If col.ColumnName = UPDATEDATE Then Continue For 'skip updatedate column
      If newRow.Item(col) <> oldRow.Item(col) Then
        sb.AppendLine($"{newRow(UPDATEDATE)} - {col.ColumnName} changed from ""{oldRow.Item(col)}"" to ""{newRow.Item(col)}"" ")
      End If
    Next

    Console.Write(sb.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED")
    Console.ReadKey()

  End Sub

  Function GetDemoDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim output As New DataTable
    output.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(UPDATEDATE, GetType(Date)))
    output.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Scope", GetType(String)))
    output.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Cost", GetType(Decimal)))
    output.Rows.Add(New Date(2023, 2, 1), "Floor and walls", New Decimal(1234))
    output.Rows.Add(New Date(2023, 2, 2), "Floor, walls, and ceiling", New Decimal(1234))
    Return output
  End Function

End Module
```

Output of this console app:

```
2/02/2023 12:00:00 AM - Scope changed from "Floor and walls" to "Floor, walls, and ceiling"
FINISHED
```

DataRow itself also supports versioning, but I'm not familiar with it: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataRow.RowState)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0

Comment: @djv You're right, so I'll reword it: How do I manipulate data that is not on the user's form?  If there's a better venue for this or a tutorial or book that covers it, please direct me.  I'm returning to VB after a 20-year hiatus and have no people-network from which to draw.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, it could be old. The book was copywrited in 2019, but it's the 16th edition.  I have not seen BindingSource or BindingNavigator before. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks!  I had tried something similar but couldn't figure out the syntax and semantics.