# How can I read and display selected SQL Server columns in C# DataGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows, forms

I want to select multiple columns from database table of SQL Server with C# windows form.

The "RollNo", "Computer", "Chemistry", "Physics", "Maths", "English", "Islamiat", "Urdu", "PakStudy" are my columns of a table "marks".

Then I have to read these columns and show their value in data grid view.

The "marks_datagrid3" is my data grid view.

I don't know why it is not running and gives error when it reads computer from database table

```
string query2 = "select RollNo,Computer,Chemistry,Physics,Maths,English,Islamiat,Urdu,PakStudy from marks where RollNo='" +  textBox1.Text + "'; ";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

SqlDataReader read2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while (read2.Read())
{
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = read2["Computer"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = read2["Chemistry"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = read2["Physics"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = read2["Maths"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = read2["English"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value = read2["Islamiat"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = read2["Urdu"].ToString();
     marks_datagrid3.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value = read2["PakStudy"].ToString();
}
```

The error is

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: What's the error? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76300228/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951980/10024425) shows how to use parameters with [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951980/10024425) shows how to bind a [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview) to a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable) and how to specify the _DataGridView_ column associated with a _DataTable_ column using [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname).

Comment: I think you mixed up rows and columns, also it should begin at 0 not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand what you are trying to do, but I think you get the error because using the wrong SqlCommand variable.
You defined variable cmd2:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
```

and used variable cmd1:

```
SqlDataReader read2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

So, change it to:

```
SqlDataReader read2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```