# how to remove 00:00:00 (DateTime) in dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview that implements keyboard input into a cell. In one of the columns I need to enter dates in the format dd/MM/yyyy. But the problem is that if I enter, for example, the date “06/21/1999”, then the actual value in the cell is “06/21/1999 00:00:00”. The task is to remove 00:00:00

I tried changing the format of the column cells, as well as changing the format of the DateTime value itself

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951980/10024425